# cargar solo markers que entran en la pantalla

Tags: google-maps

Tengo un mapa con muchos puntos marcados que me gustaria que abriesen una foto. Al abrir la página se cargan todos incluso los que estan en partes del mapa que no se ven y con la foto tarda mucho.
Como puedo hacer que solo cargue los puntos que se ven en la pantalla y a medida que se corre el mapa aparezcan y desaparezcan.?
[Aquí la página](https://wikipaint.app/ang/pintors/mapa.php)

Answer (score 2):

Para tu primera pregunta

> Como puedo hacer que solo cargue los puntos que se ven en la pantalla

Si tienes un array de coordenadas

```
let coords=  [
  {lat: -30, lng: -55 },
  {lat: -31, lng: -56 },
  {lat: -29, lng: -54 },
  {lat: -32, lng: -55 }
]
```

Y la variable del mapa

```
const mapInstance = new google.maps.Map({...});
```

Debes estar convirtiendo tus coordenadas en markers recorriendo el array (da igual si lo haces con Array.prototype.map, un bucle for, etc)

```
// ojo que coords.map es un método del array, no tiene que ver con el mapa
let markers= coords.map(coordenada => {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
      position:coordenada, 
      map: mapInstance
   });
 });
```

Si ese es tu caso, el hecho de asignarles la propiedad `map : mapInstance`  los agrega a tu mapa. Si no declaras un mapa o lo declaras explícitamente como `map: null` esos marcadores existen en memoria pero no en el mapa, lo cual es muy diferente a nivel de consumo de recursos del browser.

```
let markers= coords.map(coordenada => {
   return new google.maps.Marker({
      position:coordenada, 
      map: null
   });
});
```

Para dibujar los que entran en la zona visible del mapa, fíjate que éste tiene una propiedad `bounds` que es un `google.maps.LatLngBounds`.

```
 let bounds = mapInstance.getBounds();
```

A su vez esta clase tiene un método `contains` que responde si contiene o no una posición. Puedes recorrer los markers asignando o quitando la instancia de tu mapa para mostrarlos u ocultarlos

```
   markers.forEach(marker => {
      let visible = bounds.contains(marker.getPosition());
      marker.setMap(visible? mapInstance : null);
   });
```

o poniéndose más elaborados, podrías particionar tu arreglo de markers en dos subconjuntos:

```
    markersFuera = markers.filter(marker => {
       return !bounds.contains(marker.getPosition());
    }),
    markersEnMapa = markers.filter(marker => { 
       return bounds.contains(marker.getPosition());
    });
```

---

Para tu segunda pregunta

> y a medida que se corre el mapa aparezcan y desaparezcan.?

la respuesta más sencilla, pero ineficiente, es declarar un listener que se gatille cuando cambian los bounds de tu mapa, rehaciendo lo del principio:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(mapInstance,'bounds_changed', () => {
    let boundsActualizados = mapInstance.getBounds();
    markers.forEach(marker => {
      let visible = boundsActualizados.contains(marker.getPosition());
      marker.setMap(visible? mapInstance : null);
    });     
 });
```

este evento se gatilla incluso con paneos pequeños del mapa y por eso es ineficiente. Sería mejor utilizar alguna clase de `debounce` o `throttle` para que no pueda llamarse más que X veces en un intervalo de tiempo, o bien condicionar el refresco de markers a que el mapa se haya movido más de una cierta distancia desde el centro que tenía en el último refresco.